# OnRestoreInstance() is not calling when we change tab

Tags: android

I have three tabs in one screen.by default i am displaying first tab data.
---->
once i go second tab i am displaying an alert

when i change portrate to landscape the alert is not displaying

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use bundle in `onCreate` to restore your instance on tab change.

Comment: need to make use of life cycle methods like onSaveInstanceState and onRestoreInstanceState.